# Как посчитать всех людей на картинке с помощью библиотеки Tensorflow

Tags: python

Написала код программы, но он распознает все объекты, а мне надо подсчитать всех людей. Как правильно написать запрос?

```py
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

exec_path = os.getcwd()

detection = ObjectDetection()
detection.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detection.setModelPath(os.path.join(exec_path, "retinanet_resnet50_fpn_coco-eeacb38b.pth"))
detection.loadModel()

list = detection.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=(os.path.join(exec_path, "image2.jpg")),
                                        output_image_path=(os.path.join(exec_path,"n_image2.jpg")))
```

Наверное надо создать класс "Человек", а дальше не знаю.

Comment: Так а вы смотрели, что у вас в list получается? Хотя это плохое название для переменной

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто отфильтровать ответ. Можно используя filter:

```py
presons = filter(lambda el: el["name"] == "person", detection)
```

Comment: import tensorflow as tf

# Загружаем изображение
image = tf.io.read_file("image2.jpg")
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

# Обнаруживаем объекты

detections = tf.image.object_detection.object_detection_with_image(image, "retinanet_resnet50_fpn_coco-eeacb38b.pth")

# Считаем количество
count = 0
for detection in detections:
    if detection.class_name == "person":
        count += 1

print(count)

Comment: Дает ошибку в 9 строке

Comment: @Юлия И что это

Comment: @Юлия Лучше обновите вопрос и вставьте код туда указав ошибку

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, ты коллекцию в filter не передал.

Comment: @Юлия, 9 строка - пустая. А ещё в ответе `el["name"]`, а у тебя `detection.class_name`.

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей, https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYysX.png

Comment: @Юлия На заметку: существует пастебин

Comment: Так я тоже писала выдает ошибку

Comment: Такой код я тоже писала, еще вчера, результат ошибка -
NameError: name 'detections' is not defined. Did you mean: 'detection'?

Comment: @Юлия Ну так прочитай код ошибки